# Why is my QueryParam returning null

Tags: java, jax-rs

Disclaimer : I am not a J2EE developer. But this code works elsewhere, but this one api is going crazy.

Code

```
@GET
    @Path("GetCloseby")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public CServiceCenters getList(@QueryParam("latitude") Double latitude,
            @QueryParam("longitude") Double longitude) {
            log.info("GetCloseby searching for lat "
                    + latitude + " lng " + longitude);
```

> GetCloseby searching for lat 17.63 lng null

Calling from client

> curl http://:8080/MYWAR/MYAPI/GetCloseby?latitude=17.63&longitude=73.9

Comment: For me, with cURL on Windows, I'll get 500 status and "longitude not know as command" from Windows. I had to wrap the URL in quotes for it work correctly. Works fine on browser though. Not a big cURL user, so I couldn't say why this happens

Comment: sorry, i did not understand

Comment: I had to wrap the URL in quotes, i.e. `curl "http:/...."`. If I didn't, I would get a 500 status response, and Windows shell would give me a message "longitude is not a known command", meaning the part of the URL after the `&` did not go through, and Windows shell tried to run it as a separate command after the cURL request went through

Comment: works, please put up a answer for this so that I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am not a big cURL user, so I don't know all the nuances, and why this works. It may be a shell problem.

To get it work I had to add quotes `"` around the url

> `curl "http://:8080/MYWAR/MYAPI/GetCloseby?latitude=17.63&longitude=73.9"`

Note: I also tried to escape the `&` (without the quotes) but I would get a URISyntaxExeption with the server.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` character needs to be escaped, it has a special meaning in a shell. You can do this like this: `"abc&def"` or like this: `abc\&def`. If you try the latter: there may be other special characters in this query, so either use the first variant or you have to escape all chracters which are recognized by your shell as special characters.

Try it:

```
echo abc&def
```

This basically means:

- run the command `echo abc` in the background (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86247) which prints the string "abc"
- run the command `def` (which will probably just cause an error, as it does not exist)